# Sun lamp shadows too sharp

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I have a small army of zombies, with a sun lamp behind them. I set the sun from "No shadow" to "Ray shadow" and now the zombies have shadows. But the shadows are much too sharp. I changed the world settings to give indirect lighting, and gave it 3 bounces, but it didn't seem to affect it.
Is there a way to make the shadows from the sun more blurred, less sharp?

Comment: Try adding another lamp, perhaps a hemi or area lamp - to simulate bounced lighting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *Lamp > Shadow > Soft Size* setting. By default for a sun lamp, it is set to `0.1`, which produces sharp shadows. Increasing that number will make the shadows cast by that lamp softer.

[image]

**Note**: in order for you to see the softer shadows in your render, you need to increase the *Lamp > Shadow > Samples* value to something higher than `1`.

Example: `Soft Size = 0.1`

[image]

Example: `Soft Size = 5.0`

[image]

Comment: I thought i tried that, and it did nothing, but I looked at it again and it wasn't touched, sooo... 
Ah ha! It still did nothing, so I reread your answer, and I saw I had to mess with some other settings too (like sampling :P)

Comment: This approach simulates a penumbra, with each sample helping define an intermediate gradient within the penumbra.